# drop down list each option to take me to a different link

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am having a drop down list and I want when I select an option and then click go, to take me to an other link (each option takes me to different link)

This is my code but it doesnt seem to play.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Database Project Winter 2012
</title>
<script>
function goToNewPage(dropdownlist)
 {
 var url = dropdownlist.options(dropdownlist.selectedIndex).value;
 if (url != "")
 {
 window.open(url);
 }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="dropdown">
 <select name="list" accesskey="E">
 <option selected>Select...</option>
 <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
 <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
 <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
 <select>
 <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a simpler javascript function?

```
function goToNewPage() {
    if(document.getElementById('target').value){
        window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value;
    }
}
```

And adding an ID to the Select element?

```
<select name="list" id="target">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference inside the select tag. The value of select tag itself contains the selected option

```
function goToNewPage(dropdownlist)
 {
 var url = dropdownlist.value;
 if (url != "")
 {
 window.open(url);
 }
 }
```